# Array jumping back and forth algorithm puzzle solver

Tags: java, arrays

Hi I am having problems trying to develope code that will work for this puzzle solver
I have 2 integer arrays of 5 elements each

```
a[] = {1,1,0,2,2};
b[] = {2,2,0,1,1};
```

my program is suppose to step by step re arrange array a into array b and compare if they match.

the rules of solving are: integers 1 can only move right, integers 2 can only move left, 0 acts as a holding spot for jumping 1 over 2 vice-versa;

basically the way to solve this puzzle on paper is:

```
a b c d e
1 1 0 2 2 - >starting positiong
1 0 1 2 2 - >b moves to c therfore b is now vacated 0
1 2 1 0 2 - >d can jump over c because they are opposites so b = d
1 2 1 2 0 - > e moves over to the vacated d
1 2 0 2 1 - > c can jump over d to e because e is vacated
0 2 1 2 1
2 0 1 2 1
2 2 1 0 1
2 2 0 1 1 = b[]
```

I have written code just to declare the arrays but i have no idea how to solve any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I see two possibilities here. If the puzzles are as simple as the example, you can just recursively solve it depth first. For every status, you evaluate which rules you could use to make a step. You try them all out, calling your solve function recursively to try the next level. To evaluate you should memorize the steps taken to find the shortest route.

If things get more complex, you could look at the Minimax algorithm. If memory serves me, you need some way to evaluate the different states, for instance by the number of items that are in the right spot. You can also design heuristics to trunc possibilities that are doomed to fail.

good luck!